# How to split R,G and B channel each to double array and process it with Android Bitmap

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap

I'm new with Android and Java, and still developing Image Watermarking Application in Android with DWT - DCT - SVD method. I want to process the R, G, B channel separately in double-type array.

This is my code:

```
//Using intent, get image from album and pass the path to variable String picturePath
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int indexColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                    picturePath = cursor.getString(indexColumn);

                    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    opt.inDither = false;
                    opt.inScaled = false;
                    opt.inDensity = 0;
                    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    opt.inPurgeable = false;
                    opt.inSampleSize = 1;
                    opt.inScreenDensity = 0;
                    opt.inTargetDensity = 0;

                    sourceHostBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
```

After googling for some times, I found that after decode the image, I put the value to intArray like this :

```
int intArray = new int[sourceHostBitmap.getWidth()*sourceHostBitmap.getHeight()]
sourceHostBitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, sourceHostBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, sourceHostBitmap.getWidth(), sourceHostBitmap.getHeight());
```

From this point, I have no idea how to separate the intArray to three double array R, G and B. Please help me to accomplish it, Thanks

EDITED :
from Martin Cazares explanation, if I'm right I can write the code like below to obtain the R,G,B value of the image in double-type array

```
double[] valueRed = new double[hostWidth*hostHeight];
double[] valueGreen = new double[hostWidth*hostHeight];
double[] valueBlue = new double[hostWidth*hostHeight];

for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    valueRed[i] = (double) ((intArray[i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    valueGreen[i] = (double) ((intArray[i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
    valueBlue[i] = (double) ((intArray[i] & 0x000000FF));
}
```

EDITED AGAIN:
from @Martin suggestion, I make a mock bitmap with value alpha = 100, red = 99, green = 98, blue = 97 it will make the hex = 0x64636261 (reminder: the format stored in 0xAARRGGBB)

```
for (int i =0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = 0x64636261;
}
```

and then access the each channel value at random index :

```
int alpha, red, green, blue;
alpha = (intArray[0] & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
red = (intArray[1] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
green = (intArray[2] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
blue = (intArray[0] & 0x000000FF);
//throw it to the TextView
TextView tv = new TextView(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(alpha + " " + red + " " + green + " " + blue);
```

And the return value is like I imagine alpha = 100, red = 99, green = 98, blue = 97
try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at that point you have an array of "int"s, where each int corresponds to (0xAARRGGBB)"A=Alpha", "R=Red", "G=Green" and "B=Blue", each color takes two bytes, so, you could do something like this:

First, use a mask to isolate only the bits you're interested in, turning all other bits off:

```
pixel & 0xFF000000  // isolate most significant 8 bits (Alpha)
pixel & 0x00FF0000  // isolate next 8 bits (Red)
pixel & 0x0000FF00  // isolate next 8 bits (Green)
pixel & 0x000000FF  // isolate least significant  8 bits (Blue)
```

Then shift the bits into the least significant bits to store into a, b, c, and d (an unsigned bitshift):

```
(pixel & 0xFF000000) >>> 24 // Shift bits 24-31 to bits 0-7 Actual value of Alpha
(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16 // Shift bits 16-23 to bits 0-7 Actual value of Red
(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >>> 8  // Shift bits 8-15 to bits 0-7 Actual value of Green
(pixel & 0x000000FF)        // No need to shift the last one! Actual value of Blue
```

Hope this points you towards the right direction.

Regards!

Comment: I've just beginning image processing on android and using this method for quite some time. Never found out why use this until you explain it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your answer @Martin
by the way, I just added some code in my question based on your explanation
could you check if the code is right? if you don't mind, anyway, thanks

Comment: That seems to be right, eitherway double check by creating a mock bitmap with solid red, green and blue and make sure those values are properly stored in the arrays, also I think double is a waste of memory you should be able to work with ints... Regards!

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that processing in double will cost more resource @Martin, but most of library that I use need double as an input, so I will stick with double for a while, thanks for your suggestion, I appreciate it, and thanks too for your help :)
Regards!